# How can I loop through multiple object in java

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Hello I'm pretty new to java development and I'm having trouble with for loop
Here is my code

```
        for (MatchTeam team : players) {
        for (MatchPlayer player : team.getTeamPlayers()) {
            for (Location location : arena.getLocations()) {
                player.getPlayer().teleport(location);
            }
        }
    }
```

Object MatchTeam is holding a list of player (getTeamPlayers) and getLocations contain two different location

I've tested this code with two player and they get teleported to the same location but they should get teleported to two different location

Any idea on how to resolve this ?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "teleport" each player to each location consecutively, because you iterate through all of them, and in the end they all end up in the last location they've been teleported - the last location in the list. If you want to teleport, say, first player to first location, second player to second location and so on, you can go with this code:

```
int currentLocation = 0;
for (MatchTeam team : players) {
    for (MatchPlayer player : team.getTeamPlayers()) {
        player.getPlayer().teleport(arena.getLocations().get(currentLocation++));
        if (currentLocation == arena.getLocations().size()) {
            currentLocation = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It goes through all locations, then wraps around when the index reaches location list's size, which is an out-of-bounds index value.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer ! i tried your code, end up with the same result

Comment: @sldwn How do you initialize the lists of players and locations?

Comment: When i print my list of team i get two different team with one player per team same for the location list i get two different location, but when i print "i" from the for loop i get 0 everytime weird

Comment: @sldwn Got that. So you want to have different locations for players *across* teams. Will edit my answer shortly.